# Remove "Customer matched shipping zone..." message in woocommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

So whenever a product is added to our basket, a cart message of

> Customer matched shipping zone United Kingdom (#3)

and

> Registering shipping method instance UK Delivery (#table_rate-3)

but i dont want them.  I can't seem to see in the settings in the backend where they can be turned off.  And I dont want to remove all messages because the

> {product} has been successfully added to your cart

needs to stay.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Table Rate Shipping Extension for Woocomerce?

Comment: Hi, Yes it is installed.

Comment: Are you in debug mode?

Comment: Actually yes I am.  I didn't think about that.   Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Just to update the answer, for WooCommerce 3.0.7 the path to enable/disable Shipping Debug Mode is **WooCommerce->Shipping->Shipping Options** and check/uncheck **Enable Debug Mode**

Comment: this helped me with version 3.4.2. Thanks Ricardo!!

Answer (score 13):

To Disable the shipping debug mode you need to go to 
**WooCommerce -> System status -> Tools** and uncheck ***"Shipping Debug Mode"*** Checkbox and "Save changes"...Then clear the browser cookies and test once.. I hope your Issue will be resolved..

Answer (score 1):

Paste this after your website's address

```
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=shipping&section=options
```

and uncheck "Enable debug mode"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave debug mode enabled (because it disables the shipping cache) but still hide the message, then use this:

```
//Filter out the matching zone notice that shipping debug creates.
add_filter('woocommerce_add_message', 'wc_check_notices');
function wc_check_notices($message) {
  if (strpos($message, 'Customer matched zone') !== false) return;
  else return $message; 
}
```

You might need to adjust it for your language. I didn't check to see if it's translated (but it probably is).